# Storing entities

Tags: java, jpa

```
public class Main{

@Transient
private List<ClassB> listB;
..
}

public ClassB{
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
List<ClassC> listC;
...
}

public classC{
...
}
```

Now when I save Main class object , join table created by ClassB and ClassC is changed , whereas variable listB is transient.Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet before you are saving `Main`, you have also changed the data of the `ClassB`s it is holding, and those `ClassB` are persistent object, right?

It has nothing to do with the persistence of Main.  If you have any entities loaded and you changed them, even you are not explicitly saving them, before commit, JPA will find all dirty entities and persist the changes.

Comment: Yes you are correct :)..Can you help me solving this issue?

Comment: there is no simple way to fix that unless I know the rationale you have such model and such way of processing.  In brief, do not change the entities.  If you treat those entities to be something temporary for processing and you want to throw all changes away, do not model that as entity

Comment: Ok.Thanks will try the same